# Why is camera showing red\green\blue horizontal stripes in image?

Tags: video

This is a capture from a video from a new Blackmagic Pocket Cinema Camera.

It happens in both lenses that I have and is there, more or less, in every video image.  The light source was home led lighting; this phenomena does not happen outside in daylight.

[image]

Comment: What kind of light source is illuminating the scene of your videos?

Comment: The light source was home led lighting so Kai's answer makes sense. Does not happen outside in daylight

Comment: comment edited into the question. Welcome to the community, user89339! Comments are transitory and can be deleted at any time and without history. If there is pertinent information that comes out through comment discussion, please edit it into your question for posterity. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most probable cause is cheap LED lighting, maybe even using RGB LEDs.

As with most shutterless cams, the image information is read from the sensor in lines. This causes two known effects: The Rolling shutter effect and banding.

What you see here, seems to be banding. To dim LED lights, you have to pulse the light. Your eyes are slow enough not to notice these pulses, but the sensor can see them.

So basically you read some lines from the sensor, then the LED turns less bright, then the next lines are read, then the LED switches on again... and so forth...

What can you do about it? Either use specialized video/photo lights that switch fast enough for the sensor. Or try to even out the pictures in post, which is not an easy task.

A good test if it is related to the light source, is doing a test shot without any artificial lights on and check if the effect still occurs.

Answer (score -1):

If the lines show up on every picture taken, and appearance exactly the same, (and they're too sharp to be lens damage), than you've a problem with the camera sensor itself. It's unlikely that there's a software bug causing this. Clear the info in your camera app, wipe the system cache and reboot. If the problem is still there then it is a hardware issue